# How to merge 2 'Get' commands?

Tags: powershell

I have 2 get commands that return information and I need to merge them so they output together. Is there a way to merge the following commands? TIA

```
$output = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { 
    Get-WinEvent -logname Setup -MaxEvents 1 | 
    Select-Object TimeCreated, Message, UserId, ContainerLog
}

$output =  Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | 
    select csname, lastbootuptime
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my usual go to, although I'm sure there's a better way.

```
$output = Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { Get-WinEvent -logname Setup -MaxEvents 1 | Select-Object TimeCreated, Message, UserId, ContainerLog }

$output2 =  Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime

#Create a custom object to store the data   
  [pscustomobject]@{TimeCreated = $output.TimeCreated
 Message = $output.Message
 UserID = $output.UserID
 ContainerLog = $output.ContainerLog
 CSName = $output2.csname
 LastBoot = $output2.lastbootuptime}
```

Comment: Instead of `Select-Object`, I'd suggest using the `-Property` argument to `Get-CimInstance`.

Comment: The reason why you need to do this is that PowerShell determines the output properties (And begins to render them) with the first cmdlets in an execution.  This means that the first cmdlet defines what sort of properties are going to be rendered.  When the second command executes, if it doesn't have the *exact* same properties, those values won't be displayed.

However, if you create your own object, you get to decide how PowerShell renders it.